# How I can add spaces before and after character on HTML input

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add spaces in my input field after every time when I click any symbol in my keyboard,How I can do that?

Comment: with an input event handler

Comment: What do you need it for? I don't do homework assignments, I only help solve practical real-life problems.

Comment: I don't have event handler

Answer (score -5):

You can use &ensp to insert space in HTML